# network diagnostics and output to csv

Tags: linux, unix, network-monitoring

I'd like to know what people are using on *nix to gather output for network traffic, diagnostics, discovery. I know this is a pretty broad question but My immediate goal here is to be able to gather the reports from tools like mtr and easily output them to csv so I can present pretty spreadsheets for management. Thanks.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that Perl was designed for. If you add the output of your commands, I'm sure someone could help you get it set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest storing and retreiving the data with [RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) rather than CSV.

Even if you're not using it as part of a monitoring/graphing solution, it should make your life a whole lot easier in the long run, than dealing with CSV.

Comment: RRDtool looks to be what I want to play with. Much more robust and flexible for any future growth. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested you should look at perl using [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/).